# Error while copying data or importing data from CSV into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, data-migration

I have a CSV file -- > named -- myWidechar1.csv and the data in it is as follows:

```
1~"ϴAnthony"~"Grosse"~"1980-02-23"~"65000.00"
2~"❤Alica"~"Fatnowna"~"1963-11-14"~"45000.00"
3~"☎Stella"~"Rossenhain"~"1992-03-02"~"120000.00"
```

Copy Command in PostgreSQL is as follows:

```
Copy dbo.myWidechar From 'D:\temp\myWidechar1.csv' DELIMITER '~' null as 'null'  encoding 'windows-1251' CSV; select 1;
```

But problem is I am getting the below error while importing data into PostgreSQL:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "WIN1251": 0x00 CONTEXT: 
>   COPY mywidechar, line 3 SQL state: 22021

I need the data to remain same even in PostgreSQL as I am migrating data from SQL Server 2000 instance.

Can some one please help me in resolving this issue ?

Comment: From the error, it looks like the encoding is not proper. I don't see your characters listed on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251

Comment: @Jacob, can you please advise on what encoding I should use? I am new to PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm not a Posgres person either, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916853/postgresql-copy-encoding-how-to

Comment: If this is coming from windows-land then that may be UTF-16LE. I would agree that the heart and phone are not in the Win-1251 encoding. Telephone is 0x260E, for instance. Although if the normal characters (0-9a-zA-Z) aren't also two byte, then you may have luck just going UTF-8 and seeing what shakes out.

Comment: If it really is UTF-16, you'll have to convert the data to something else first.

Comment: With UTF-16 or UTF-16LE, I am getting below error:
ERROR:  argument to option "encoding" must be a valid encoding name

Comment: I was speaking more to the encoding of the file. That needs to be determined first before you can figure out what type of encoding you will instruct Postgres to use. Unfortunately Postgres doesn't support UTF-16 (Either endianess) so if you determine your file to be UTF-16 then you will have to convert. Here's what I would do. On the Linux command line issue the command `file yourfile` and see what it spits out. If it says it's UTF-16 then you will need to convert: `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 yourfile > yourfile.out` then import `yourfile.out` into Postgres using `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: If, on the other hand the result of `file yourfile` is `utf-8` then just go straight to postgres import with `en_US.utf-8` and let 'er rip. If it spits out something more `ascii-ish` then you can always just `iconf -f <wahtever> -t utf-8 yourfile > yourfile.out` and again import into Postgres with `en_US.utf-8`. I'd be happy to write this up as an answer if any of this ends up being useful. The big takeaway though is figuring out the encoding of your file before trying to guess at what postgres needs.

Comment: Lastly, I would bet good money that if this data was in SQL Server and exported on Windows that your file is `UTF-16LE`. Windows, for whatever reason, really likes that clunky bloated unicode encoding. `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 yourfile > yourfile.out` is *probably* going to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you JNevill. I will give it a shot and keep everyone posted...it might be helpful for future reference