# I am getting the error message "ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "WIN1251": 0x00"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to load the CSV to my postgres database but I am getting the above error message:

My query is :

```
COPY dbo.tbl(col1,col2) 
FROM 'C:\Data\dbo.tbl.csv' DELIMITER ',' null as 'null'  encoding 'windows-1251' CSV;
```

I tried this link for reference:https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/'

Can someone please help me what is the issue. I am new to postgres database.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916853/postgresql-copy-encoding-how-to

Comment: Check database and file encoding. for database `psql my_database -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'` . Which version of windows you are using  ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the encoding of your client? You can concatenate the `set client encoding` and the `copy`commands with a semicolon, e.g. `"SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'WIN1251'; COPY dbo.tbl FROM FROM 'C:\Data\dbo.tbl.csv'"`

Comment: @JimJones I tried what you ask for, but it is giving me the same error

Comment: Weird. Are you sure the file is encoded using `WIN1251`? I recall having the same issue and being able to solve it using`SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8'; COPY ...`

Comment: Ah.. I just realized your problem is about `null` values expresses as `0x00`, which is indeed invalid in PostgreSQL. If you're using linux, try replacing or delete these values using `sed`, `perl -pe`, etc. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, I have csv file with encoding 'WIN874' and postgres client encoding is 'UTF-8'. I can use `copy` command without problems.

To make sure that your file encoding is 'WIN1251', you can open your csv file in visual studio code. It will show file encoding on the right bottom pane.

[image]

Comment: Thank mate. I was fighting with this for last two hours and your post saved me.